# How to Create a Priority Queue in C++ as a member variable?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

How do I create a priority queue as a member variable and use a member function as the comparator?

I've tried using c-style function pointers but can't figure out how to have a function pointer as a member variable to a member function.

```
class CallCenter
{
    std::function<bool(Employee*, Employee*)> m_comp;
public:
    CallCenter() : m_comp(Compare) {}

    bool Compare(Employee* a, Employee* b);
    std::priority_queue<Employee*, std::vector<Employee*>, m_comp>> m_available;
};
```

I'm also getting errors trying to set the function pointer to a member variable.

Comment: `bool Compare(Employee* a, Employee* b);` -- That is not a C-style function.  It is a non-static, C++ member function, a different thing altogether.

Answer (score 0):

`Compare` is a non-static member function, and cannot be called like `Compare(a, b)`.
You need to make the function `static` or `friend`:

```
static bool Compare(Employee* a, Employee* b);
```

Or

```
friend bool Compare(Employee* a, Employee* b);
```